# Circular Queue DLL not working as expected for push and display

Tags: c, queue, project, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

I converted my file into a project file and it now doesnt work like before.

I am using Circular Queue DLL to insert,delete, and display the values.

My problem is that if I were to enter the ff number respectively: **5,4,3** I get **3, 2810, 0**. Which is very very wrong. I have been working on this for hours now and I'm thinking turning it to a project file might have caused some of my variables not to be properly declared or something. Also proj file is a requirement.

here are my codes:

Header:

```
#ifndef CIRCDLL_H
#define CIRCDLL_H


struct node{
    int val;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;    
};

typedef struct node NODE;


int push();
int display();
NODE* create_node(int info);
#endif
```

Main:

```
#include "circdll.h"
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


NODE *new, *ptr, *prev;
NODE *first = NULL, *last = NULL;
int number = 0;

void main()
{
    int lim,choice,value,i;
    clrscr();

     /*get number of nodes*/
     printf("Input # of nodes: ");
     scanf("%d",&lim);


    for(;;)
    {
        printf("\n\nMENU: \n");
        printf("[1]Enqueue\n[2]Dequeue\n[3]Exit\nChoice: ");
        scanf("%s",&choice);

        clrscr();
        switch(choice)
        {
            case '1':
                      printf("Input value: \n");
                      for(i = 1; i <= lim; i++)
                      {
                        /*scanf("%d",&value);*/
                        push();
                        /* insert_lnode(value); */
                       }
                      display();
                      break;
            case '2':
                      /*delete();
                      display();*/
                      break;
            case '3':
                      exit(1);
                      break;
            default:
                      printf("Incorrect choice!\n\n\n");
                      break;
        }
    }
}
```

Create:

```
#include "circdll.h"
#include<stdio.h>



NODE* create_node(int info){
    int number =0;
    NODE *new;

    number++;
    new = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    new->val = info;
    new->next = NULL;
    new->prev = NULL;
    return new;
}
```

Push:

```
#include "circdll.h"
#include<stdio.h>

int push(){

    int info;
    NODE *new, *ptr, *prev,*first, *last;

    scanf("%d",&info);
    new = create_node(info);

    if (first == last && first == NULL){
        first = last = new;
        first->next = last->next = NULL;
        first->prev = last->prev = NULL;
    }else{
        last->next = new;
        new->prev = last;
        last = new;
        last->next = first;
        first->prev = last;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Display:

```
#include "circdll.h"
#include<stdio.h>

int display(){
    int i,number;
    NODE *ptr, *prev;
    NODE *first, *last;
    if (first == last && first == NULL)
        printf("\nQueue is empty");
    else{
        for (ptr = last, i = 0;i < number;i++,ptr = ptr->prev){
            printf("\n%d", ptr->val);
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem: Both `int push()` and `display()` are using uninitialized local variables: `first`, `last`.

This also implies the compilers warnings are not fully enabled.  Insure they are on.

---

Although OP's previous files are not shown, it is likely that these routines used a common (global) set of `first`, `last`.

To continue with OP's original approach of a global, define `NODE *first = NULL`, `NODE *last = NULL;` in  display.c and declare them in header.h with `extern NODE *first;`, `extern NODE *last;`  (remove from main.c.)  Likely additional work is needed.

---

A better approach requires more work, of which I will present just an idea to get started.

Declare the head of the `NODE` where it is used and pass into functions `create_node()`, `push()`, and `display()` the head node address.

```
int push(NODE *Head) {
  int info;
  NODE *new, *ptr, *prev;
  NODE *first = Head;
  NODE *last = Head;
  ...

int foo() {
  NODE Head;
  push(&Head);
  ...
```

---

[Edit] Sample changes:

Get rid of `number`. It is not needed.  When count is needed, simple travel the Q until you return to the beginning.

Note: below Q model has `last->next` pointing to `first` and `first->prev` pointing to `last`.

```
typedef struct node node_T;

void push(node_T **head) {
  node_T *newnode;
  int info;

  scanf("%d", &info);
  newnode = create_node(info);
  if (*head == NULL) {
    *head = newnode;
    newnode->next = newnode;
    newnode->prev = newnode;
  } else {
    node_T *LastNode = (*head)->prev;
    LastNode->next = newnode;
    newnode->next = *head;
    (*head)->prev = newnode;
    newnode->prev = LastNode;
  }
}

void foo() {  // Sample usage
  node_T *Q = NULL;  
  push(&Q);
  push(&Q);
  push(&Q);
}
```

Comment: why is *first and *last declared as NULL in display.c?

Comment: The (unnamed) header file contains the _declaration_.  In one of the *.c files (or a new one) should exist the _definition_ of `first` and `last`.  I picked `display.c` out of convenience.  --- But I suggest you try the 2nd approach.  Create a head node in the function that uses the Q and pass that &head node to each Q function call.

Comment: if it is not much trouble can you provide more details regarding the 2nd approach as I am having a very hard time continuing with this approach. for example push, why do i have to add to the parameter the head? thank you and hope you can help me with this, i would really appreciate it. I am just not use to using project files at all.

Comment: @hushpuppies See edit.  Think of using your routines, not with just 1 queue, but with separate instances of a circular queue.  How to keep track of what queue is being changed - by passing the head of the queue (or a reference) to your routines.